# How to validate form data first before uploading a file?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, multer

I have a `/register` user service with form data such as firstName, lastName, profileImage..etc.

I am using `MulterModule` for parsing the formData but the problem is that profileImage is getting uploaded first and then the validation is done by the ValidationPipe.

I know that in nest.js `middlewares` are ran first and then `Pipes` are run but I don't know `how can I make my validation first before uploading process.`

Now, for me this is a critical problem because I am working in an IT firm and we are building a social media like application. So, there are going to be lots of videos & image uploads along with other details. Hence, the upload directory is going to be flooded with all the unused files.

And also I know that this is not a problem of Nest.js but however, I searched everywhere but there is no solutions given anywhere.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: You should use fileFilter as it's written in documentation https://github.com/expressjs/multer#filefilter

Comment: @cojack But wouldn't that defeat the purpose of validating form using DTO through ValidationPipe?

Comment: I know this is not what you are looking for but I think I'd go with a 2-steps solution. The first step (`/register`) would validate the form and register the User. This would allow generating his/her credentials (e.g. a JWT) and return them. With these credentials, the client now has the authorization to upload the "profile image". From the UX/client perspective, this can be seen as a single step (but two requests will be sent to the backend).

This allows you to both: avoid the useless storage **and** allow only registered users to upload content.

Comment: @VinceOPS No, this is not what I am looking for and besides what would happen if after registration I failed to upload the image? Let's say the image was too big or any other issue then what?

Comment: Not everything can be done in the same way, it's just how it's, you can overcome your patience or get used to